# Edit S3 doc with google docs and store it back to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-docs

I am trying to write a program that would allow my users to edit their S3 docs with Google Docs and then the program would store it back to their S3 bucket.

Any ideas on how to start?

I know its possible to simple open a document with google docs by supplying a URL.

Comment: Hi there )) did you have any luck to find out how to manage desired flow? I know that almost 6 years passed. And hope something changed ))

Answer (score 1):

While Google Docs is able to open a document from a URL, it cannot "save" the document back to Amazon S3.

Your users would need to save the document within Google Docs (on Google Drive), then your program would need to retrieve that document and save it into Amazon S3.

The problem is... how do you trigger your program to perform the export?

As an alternative, you could synchronize between Google Drive and Amazon S3. See:

- [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/amazon-s3/google-drive/)
- [CloudHQ](https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-sync-amazon-s3-and-google-drive/)
- [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/how-to-sync-google-drive)
- ...and probably many more!

Comment: The thing is, I want to do this on my own server, like making a replica of Zapier or cloudHQ, so was looking for directions.